GitHub не правильно фильтрует папки
Изучаю Java, читаю книгу по главам, в каждой главе несколько заданий solution 1.0 solution 2.0 и тд. выкладываю всё на GitHub и вместо
Chapter 1.0
...
Chapter 9.0
Chapter 10.0
Получаю
Chapter 1.0
Chapter 10.0
На сколько это корректно ?

Сортировка по алфавиту, буква 1 идёт перед буквой 2, всё нормально

как пофиксить ?

Получаю Chapter 1.0 Chapter 10.0 - как и где получаешь?

@Dimka так работает "алфавитная" сортировка, это стандартное поведение, что Вы фиксить собрались? Строки сортируются посимвольно от начала к концу. "Chapter 10.0" будет идти перед "Chapter 2.0", потому что символ "1" в "10.0" меньше символа "2" в "2.0"

Почему?
Почему очередь идет Chapter 1, Chapter 10, Chapter 11, Chapter 2 ...?
Ответ
Потому что сортируется строка, а не число в строке.
Программа берет Chapter 10 и Chapter 2 и решает - какой ставить раньше. Начиная спереди сравнивает символы в строке, и если они равны смотрит дальше. Поскольку у обоих начало Chapter  доходит до 2 из первой строки, и 1 - из второй. Поскольку '1' < '2' ставит Chapter 1... раньше, чем Chapter 2....
Как решить?
Можете пронумеровать вот так: Chapter 001, Chapter 002, ..., Chapter 010, Chapter 011 ...
